# Ask how to pronounce advisor's last name?

Tags: advisor, etiquette, undergraduate, personal-name

I am an undergraduate working with an advisor, but I do not know how to pronounce his/her last name. I have talked with several different people who work in the department, and have heard the name pronounced several different ways.

Is there a polite way of asking an advisor how to pronounce his/her last name?

Comment: Just ask, same as with anyone else. I don't think this is specific to academia, hence my down-vote.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general etiquette

Comment: You're almost there! A cut and paste from your question with edited pronouns seems fine to me: "I do not know how to pronounce your last name. I have talked with several different people who work in our department, and have heard your name pronounced several different ways."

Comment: It's fun to watch students try to pronounce your foreign name, all the time with a poker face.

Comment: But don't call his last name if it is "Voldemort."

Comment: I you are not comfartable asking him openly, how are you going to work with him comfortably?

Comment: @jinawee It's not necessarily uncomfortable, but just asking in a polite way.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> By the way, I have heard your last name pronounced a few different ways and I want to make sure I get it right. Can you teach me the correct way to pronounce it?

Comment: ... and by the way, what would you like me to call you.

Comment: I'm fairly routinely asked questions of this kind. Although I understand why they ask, I disagree with the premise. If I were asked this, I would ask back "What do you mean by "correct way"?" A better way to ask would be "How do _you_ pronounce your name?" or "What would you like me to call you?" (as StrongBad said).

Comment: I disagree. The correct way to say my name is the way I choose.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Nice principle, but not always possible. Sometimes the problem is that it is extremely hard to pronounce the name correctly. For example, I live in Germany but I am Dutch and my last name contains a sound that just does not exist in German. I am not offended when people ask, and I will explain them how to do so, but at same time I will tell them not to worry about it and that I will listen to anything that is close enough.

Comment: @MaartenBuis: Okay but that's not the same as saying that foreign approximations are now the "correct" way ;p

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Tell that to my local Starbucks barista, who insists on calling me "Holly" and looking at me like 'you have a girls name' every day!

Comment: @OllieFord: Haha :P I always give the Starbucks cashiers random names. One week I'm Peter, the next I'm Javier.. it's very amusing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So I didn't claim that 'foreign approximations' are 'correct', I just took issue with the notion of there being one 'correct' pronunciation in the first place. I want to be helpful to my interlocutors, so my _preferred_ pronunciation changes according to who I'm talking to (and what country I am in), since the way I say my name in my own language is unpronounceable to anyone not speaking my language.

Comment: Call me ... anytime :-)

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun "Hi, Late-For-Dinner."

Comment: @Dan - touché. Brilliant!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I once asked my MS advisor whether his last name (Eppstein) was correctly pronounced "Epsteen" or "Epstine".  He answered "Either".

Answer (score 12):

I agree with the direct approach in the other answer, but if you'd like an indirect approach (that can be done before a first meeting), try calling the professor's office phone number when you know he or she is not there and listening to how the name is pronounced on voice mail.

Comment: anything to avoid actual communication.

Comment: *goes up to Professor Hughes* "So I pronounce your name .... 'Hello'.."?

Comment: @Spork just a day in the life of a CS undergrad (and even grad, I heard) student.